# Haskell Function Giving Wrong Output

Tags: string, list, function, haskell, recursion

I have this prompt: make a function that takes a string and sees if every other letter is an element of ['a' .. 'f']

So I have this:

```
betweenAF :: String -> Bool
betweenAF (x:y:xs)  
    | x `elem` ['a' .. 'f'] = True
    | otherwise = betweenAF xs
betweenAF _ = False
```

Now it works on the first letter of the string, like if I put betweenAF "all", but it doesn't work if I put betweenAF "lla". Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: It doesn't work: `betweenAF "all"` returns `True` when it should be `False`.

Comment: `betweenAF "lla"` yields `false` as expected: https://ideone.com/E54So5 .

Comment: `(x:y:xs)` only matches strings of length 2 or more; your `_` case catches all singleton lists *and* the empty list, not all of which should have the same return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the cases reversed. If `x` *is* in the range, you are only part way done and have to recurse. If `x` is *not* in the range, you can immediately return False because it doesn't matter if the other letters are in the range or not. The property is vacuously true for an empty list because there are no letters that *aren't* in the desired range.

```
betweenAF :: String -> Bool
betweenAF [x] = betweenAF [x,x] -- hack to handle odd-length lists
betweenAF (x:y:ys) | x `elem` ['a'..'f'] = betweenAF ys
                   | otherwise = False
betweenAF [] = True
```

---

Better version, thanks to Will Ness:

```
betweenAF (x:xs) = x `elem` ['a'..'f'] && betweenAF (drop 1 xs)
betweenAF [] = True
```

since `drop 1 [x]` and `drop 1 []` both evaluate to `[]`.

Comment: you missed the `| otherwise`, but *otherwise* (drum sting) perfect.

Comment: I left it out, since I am conflating "`x` not in the list" with "`(x:y:xs)` didn't match". Of course, then I forgot to handle the empty list, which I then added separately, so I'm going to take a moment to decide if this is better than an explicit `otherwise`...

Comment: I think omitting the otherwise is incorrect anyway, isn't it? What does Haskell do if it pattern matches but no guards match?

Comment: Yeah, I'm blanking on an elegant way to handle that.

Comment: maybe [this](https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/9a9688dc872a032866240a912a8eb6e7)?

Comment: I don't really like the duplicated `elem` test, but it certainly isn't *worse* than what I have.

Comment: agreed I don't like it either, but the alternative is testing `length xs` every recursion which I felt was less performant.

Comment: how about ``betweenAF [] = True; betweenAF (x:ys) = (x `elem` ['a'..'f']) && betweenAF (drop 1 ys)``.

Comment: I think my favorite is [this](https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/11ebc9630e6c01ec800513071d6ad421) where you pull out every other character first, then use `all` with the predicate.

Comment: @WillNess Ah, yes. I forgot about `drop 1`, which basically acts like `tail` in the ways we want.

Answer (score 2):

The function works. Just, what it does is this: it sees whether *there is* **any** even-indexed element which is in `'a'..'f'`. Whereas you apparently want it to see whether **all** elements are in the range.

Apply simple logical inversion to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Just because I spent a few minutes on this, I wanted to point out another possible solution. Instead of pattern matching against the whole string, you can pull out every other character and use `all` to check them all against the predicate. This removes the need to do any explicit recursion or pattern matching.

```
betweenAF :: String -> Bool
betweenAF = all (flip elem ['a'..'z']) . everyOther where
  everyOther xs = [v | (k,v) <- zip (cycle [True, False]) xs, k]
```

`everyOther` is equivalent to `map snd . filter (fst) . zip (cycle [True, False])` and `flip elem ['a'..'z']` is equivalent to `\x -> elem x ['a'..'z']`. All told this can be re-written as:

```
betweenAF = all (flip elem ['a'..'z']) . map snd . filter fst . zip (cycle [True, False])
```

This, however, is rather uglier than sin!

Comment: for me, using ``(`elem` ['a'..'z'])`` would make the last variant more tolerable, borderline OK even.

Answer (score 1):

Just for some practice i guess you may also do as follows;

```
everyOtherInAF :: String -> Bool
everyOtherInAF = all id . zipWith ($) (cycle [(`elem` ['A'..'F']), const True])

*Main> everyOtherInAF "AsErCgHm"
False
*Main> everyOtherInAF "AsErCgFm"
True
*Main> everyOtherInAF "AsErjgFm"
False
*Main> everyOtherInAF "AsErAgFm"
True
```